# How to get array index in validation message Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-validation

These arrays I put into `Laravel Validator` as arguments:

```
['item.*' => 'string'] // rules

['item.*.string' => 'Item number (index) is not string'] // messages
```

I want to have `index number` in validation message. Code above is just for demonstration and does not work. How to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this or use this one

```
    'name' : [ { 'value' : 'raju' } , { 'value' : 'rani'} ]
```

and validate it by

```
    'name.*' or 'name.*.value' => 'required|string|min:5'
```

The message will be

```
    'name.*.required' => 'The :attribute is required'       
    'name.*.value.required' => 'The :attribute is required'
```

I think it will help to you..

Try this one,

```
public function messages()
{
    $messages = [];
    foreach ($this->request->get('name') as $key => $value){
        $messages['name.'. $key .'.required'] = 'The item '. $key .'  is not string';
    }
    return $messages;
}
```

Comment: well I need index to be displayed in message. This will display just attribute name.

Comment: @Fusion I think, The :attribute place will give name.0, name.1 and etc, So, it is not enough for require.?

Comment: @Fusion {
  "name.0": [
    "item number name.0 is not a string."
  ]
}   this is my alter output for your knowledge.

Comment: Answer is helpful, however i would like to have something like: 'name.*.value.required' => 'The error is located at :index'  ( notice there is no attribute mentioned). It is possible to parse message for index, however I find it cumbersome.

Comment: @Fusion please use the message function style and it will return the index value.

Answer (score 1):

In new version of Laravel you can try:

```
'item.*.string' => 'Item number :position is not string'
```

**:position** will be replaced with human readable number, for example 0 index converting to 1.