# rename attribute item array in request validation laravel

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I am working with the laravel validations in form request and this time I need to validate a data array something like this:

```
public function rules()
{
    $rules = [
       'products.*.quantity' => 'required|integer',
       'products.*.dimension' => 'required|min:5|max:16',
       'products.*.description' => 'required|min:5',
    ];

    return $rules;
}
```

where products is the array where I have each of the items, this works however it gives me a message more or less like this: `The products.1.quantity field is required.`
I need to change the name of the attribute, I know it is possible to change the name inside the messages method giving a new value to `products.*. quantity` for example `products.*. quantity => "quantity"`, however I would also like to specify the key of the item that is failing and at the end have a message like this:

`The quantity in item 1 field is required.`
then is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get array index in validation message Laravel 5.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36571628/how-to-get-array-index-in-validation-message-laravel-5-2)

Answer (score -2):

Search for this file `resources/lang/xx/validation.php` and modify custom entry with your custom messages

```php
'custom' => [
    'products.*.quantity' => [
        'required' => 'Your custom message',
    ]
]
```

Comment: That doesn't answer the question that he posted, he wants to include the `$index` to the message which is returned. Your solution leaves that out, the link provided by Don't Panic, seems to be a better solution as it does handle that issue.